# Playing Audio file stored Application path of Android Application

Tags: android, media-player

I am trying to play a wav file which I have stored in application path but i am getting error like Media Player error(-38,0) . It says Media Player invalid

The same file when i store in sdCard Media Player plays it without any error

Hear is my code for getting the file from Application path

File sourceFile=new File(context.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/source.wav");

Answer (score 1):

try this url http://www.bogotobogo.com/Android/android24MediaB.html#AudioPlay